# Laravel VentureCraft/revisionable. How to display changes in pivot tables or related models in the model history?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, revisionable

I have a Users() table and a Roles() table. They have a relation pivot table users_has_roles(n-n relation). I can see in the user's history the addition of new roles - adding rows to the pivot table? Or see changes in the user's history in some rows of the pivot table or changes in the roles table (not only in the history of roles)?